# How to call quoted-insert?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to write a function which will send a Control-C character followed by RET.

If I am in the shell, I know that I have to do `C-q C-c` to send a Control-C. I'd like to write a function that will just do this for me.

I've gotten as far as seeing that the `quoted-insert` function is what I need to use but it's not clear to me from the docs on how to call it. Can anyone offer a pointer?

Comment: Are you looking for something different than?: `(insert "abcdefg . . ")` or perhaps `(global-set-key (kbd "M-!") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "¡")))`; or are you interested in the functions `comint-send-string` and `comint-send-input` to send input to the shell process behind the scenes (e.g., without seeing the input)?

Comment: NOTE:  The character `^C` doesn't show up on StackOverflow -- so imagine that `^C` is in between the double quotes following `"*shell*"` -- there is no need for a return or `\n` because `comint-send-input` takes care of that:  `(defun send-ctrl-q-ctrl-c-ret () (interactive) (comint-send-string "*shell*" "") (comint-send-input)) (global-set-key [f5] 'send-ctrl-q-ctrl-c-ret)`

Comment: I just want to automate ```C^q C^c``` so that I don't have to type out that combo. I just want to hit ```C^c``` in my ```*shell*``` session and be done with it.

Comment: Did the sample function not work for you?  Instead of F5 you can make the keyboard shorcut anything you want and you can make it mode-specific depending on whether its shell-mode or something else.  Remember to insert a literal `^C` between the two quotation marks immediately following `*shell*` when writing the function -- that doesn't show up on StackOverflow.  The example assumes your open process is named `*shell*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I wanted to do was this:

```
(defun send-control-c ()
  (interactive)
  "Inserts quoted ^C into the buffer and hits enter"
  (insert "")
  (comint-send-input))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to confuse "send" and "insert" and it's not clear exactly what you mean by "control-C" (is it the ASCII char with code 3, or is it the signal usually associated with the C-c key via stty).
But you might want to start with:

```
(insert "\C-c\r")
```

or

```
(process-send-string <yourprocess> "\C-c\r")
```